# Why was the tag [arras.io] deleted?

Tags: support, tags

Earlier, I [posted a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397807/when-being-killed-by-an-object-or-non-player-does-that-entity-gain-the-xp-i-had) that had the now nonexistent tag [arras.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arras.io). Now this tag is gone. I also saw another question (that probably got deleted) about not being able to connect to "Extended Arras" (whatever that is) that also had the tag [arras.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arras.io). Why was this tag deleted, and is it possible for somebody to re-add it since I am not at 300 reputation yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question was edited to remove the [arras.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arras.io) back on [June 20th, 2022](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/397807/timeline#history_d78ebf55-32a0-452b-9f56-eb3e6bc2e174) with the reason being:

> Arras.io seems to be just context not what is actually being asked about

Since the [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395430/cannot-connect-to-extended-arras) you mention was deleted, the tag no longer had any questions, which means it was [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/342074) once the automated process ran.

Comment: How would I re-add the tag back? Do I have to get to 300 reputation first and then create it?

Comment: @Ender since you need 300 reputation to create tags - yes.  But read the reason provided by pppery as to why they edited out the tag in the first place.  Is the question _really_ about arras.io? It seems the diep.io tag is really all you needed.  No need to spin up extra tags.  If you find yourself asking a question _specific_ to arras.io, then ask it, and someone with 300+ reputation can add the tag (usually OP's will leave a comment on their question asking for someone to create the tag).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! You are a very helpful moderator on this site :)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the automated process ran?" What automated process? How does it work?

Comment: @Enderman it's a background job that runs everyday at that time. It's apart of the Stackexchange network (it runs on ALL SE sites). We have no control over it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!